# Upgrade Apache 2.2.22 to 2.2.26 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I've been scouring the internet for what should be a seemingly simple process, but I can't seem to get this to work.

I currently have Apache 2.2.22 running on my Ubuntu Server, and I simply need to upgrade to the latest release. Ubuntu has not updated their repository yet, so I can't use apt-get (sadly).

I found [this post](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-install-apache-243-wordpress) detailing how to install 2.4.3 from a .tar.bz2 so I figured I would try that. I uninstalled Apache 2.2.22 and followed all the steps (but used a .tar for 2.2.26 of course).

When I run `/etc/apache2/bin/apachectl start`, it doesn't complain, but the web server doesn't appear to be working. Going to website just results in Chrome saying "The page could not be displayed". No error 500, nothing. (I should note I ran configure like this: `./configure --prefix=/etc/apache2`)

Running `service apache2 start` simply results in it saying No Apache MPM Package Installed.

Any ideas on how to perform this update?

Comment: Did you copy your configuration to the place the new server expects it? You can't just blindly follow random posts you stumbled into on the internet and expect everything to work...

Comment: I wouldn't say I blindly followed it. I instructed configure to prefix the path with the location of my previous apache2 installation. The configuration files are still there, and the sites are enabled. That said, even if they weren't, I theoretically still should've seen an "It works!" page, right?

Comment: Your configuration files are in `/etc/apahe2/etc`? Your binaries have always been in `/etc/apache2/bin`? If so you're blatantly ignoring [hier(7)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/man7/hier.7.html) but that's a different argument. Yes I would expect an "It works!" page - if you're not getting one *you* need to troubleshoot: Verify your configuration files are where the new server expects them. Check your logs (and tell us what they say). etc...

Comment: My configuration files have been in `/etc/apache2/` because that is where Ubuntu installs Apache when installing from the repository. I was simply maintaining the location of Apache to reduce the number of variables changing. In any case, I'll keep playing around with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debian/Ubuntu package apps like Apache differently from the Red Hat world, and Suse and others may be different again. I see there aren't any Ubuntu deb packages or RH rpms beyond 2.2.22 but that Apache has a 2.4.7. So Ubuntu, RH, and Apache src build will probably put configurations in different places, and indeed, change the things are handled ( like mods for instance).

So once you save off your configuration, I'd purge apache to delete files, making sure the daemons are not running, and everything really was deleted. Then build the src from Apache.

The problem with this is that you won't easily be able to upgrade later, so you'll have to judge your level of patience and actual need for the upgrade before you embark.